# Did Captain Terrell and Cdr. Chekov have their phasers when they encountered Khan and his group outside of the Botany Bay?

Tags: star-trek, the-wrath-of-khan

In the movie *Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan,* did Captain Terrell and Commander Chekov have their phasers when they encountered Khan and his group outside of the Botany Bay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes and no (but mostly no).

The [original screenplay](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek-II-The-Wrath-of-Khan.html) doesn't mention them having any weapons when they're confronted by Khan's men, nor do they appear to have any [in the film itself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXeanZB8J40).

> 22   EXT. CARGO HOLD AIRBAY                                      22
>
> Terrell and Chekov emerge, helmeted, then stop dead.
>
> 23   ANGLE - THEIR POV                                           23
>
> A RING OF SUITED FIGURES has them surrounded.

[image]

That being said, the [official novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Wrath_of_Khan_(novel)) does mentions Chekov having a phaser. The ring of people had the drop on them and they were swiftly disarmed.

> "Beam us up!" Chekov cried into his transmitter.
>
> As he grabbed at his phaser, one of the suited figures lunged forward,
> disarmed him, and knocked him back into the airlock.